# How do I get my tools back?

Tags: harvest-moon-gb

I was talking to the sprite behind my tool shed one day, and he offered to upgrade my hammer. Then I spoke to him again and he offered to upgrade my hoe. It's been longer then he said it would be to complete the upgrades, so now he has both my tools, and won't give them back.  How can I get them back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sprite will upgrade your tool for you, and he tells you to come in 24 hours.  What you've probably done is give him your tools, sleep, and come back to him.  This is incorrect.  He means come back in 24 *real-time* hours.  From the [Events page on Fogu](http://fogu.com/hm1/events.htm):

> Turn on the Timer feature (press SELECT twice to see it) so the Sprites help you, then turn off your Gameboy. When you go back to your game the Sickle will be sitting on the bench inside your Tool Shed.

I am unsure if the Timer is required to be turned on, but you do need to wait an actual day for you to get your upgraded tool.

Comment: I'll check that out and post tomorrow if it worked or not. Thanks